How to prevent a BelongsToMany relationship from allowing `attach`
I have several purchasable models that have a many to many relation ship with the customer model. As such I am using a BelongsToMany relationship.
 BelongsToMany::make(__('Courses'), 'courses', Course::class)
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),

To ensure a sepeate checkout process cannot be bypassed, I need to disable the attach action of the relationship:

How can I prevent the course from being attached to the user?

are you using automatic eager load method to retrieve that data? and please mention what version of laravel framework you are using

BelongsToMany::make(__('Courses'), 'courses', Course::class)
->sortable()
->searchable()
->disableAttaching(),

try doing this

This does not work, that function does not exist.

public function authorizedToAttachAny(NovaRequest $request, $model)
    {
      return false;
    }


Override this method in the nova resource.
Also, found this in official documentation, if you want to try out
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/authorization.html#authorizing-attaching-detaching
